# Is $f(i)=n-i, f:\mathbb{N_n}\rightarrow \mathbb{N_n}$ a bijection?

Tags: functions, natural-numbers

My text states that $f:\mathbb{N_n}\rightarrow \mathbb{N_n}$ where $f(i) = n-i$ is a bijection.

I am not convinced about this because if $i=n$, then $f(n)=n-n=0$ but $0 \notin \mathbb{N_n}$. Therefore, $f$ is not a function.

Is the text implicitly assuming $0 \in \mathbb{N_n}$ in this particular example? Previous examples of $\mathbb{N_n}$ states that $\mathbb{N_n}=\{1,2,\dots, n\}$.

Comment: They must mean $\mathbb N_n = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ in this context. They could also mean $\mathbb N_n = \{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$, but I think that's less likely; excluding the endpoint is usually indicative of zero-indexing in my experience.

Comment: It could also be a typo, with $f(i)=n+1-i$ intended instead.

Comment: Everything of value having been said... close?

Comment: What reason to give for close?